What is suitable tool for filtering large ranges of ips
[question replaced from server fault]
I'm trying to setup OpenVPN connection that would work only with certain sites and domains (filtering) (installed via https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install). First tool I discovered was iptables. Setting this thing up was easy enough, considering I'm newbie in this topic. After this VPN connection was working as intended.
However, I found out that iptables won't resolve domains that constantly swaps their IP addresses (e.g. youtube.com).
What I've tried (let's keep youtube.com as an example):

adding youtube.com to /etc/hosts with fixed IP and then adding same IP to iptables. Doesn't help.
reject/drop package that matches domain decoded with some of alghoritms (source1, source2)

Now I'm stuck wondering how filter-out such domains.

You're probably not going to be able to do this at the IP layer (i.e. with firewall rules). You'll probably need to block DNS traffic so you can force your clients to use a DNS server you control, and configure that DNS server to block queries for the blacklisted domains. Kind of like what a Pi-hole does for ad servers. In fact a Pi-hole is probably a good solution for you, because you can add your own blacklisted domains to it.

@Spiff, thanks! I'll explore this option. But, because of lack of experience in administrating it can take some time for me to learn.
